# Vertical alignment between two lines of text

Tags: vertical-alignment, alignment, vertical

I'd very much appreciate a bit of help on this subject.

I am trying to obtain an alignment between those two lines as shown in the picture below.

[image]

I can only manage to do it like this :

[image]

I also tried the tabular version, but no success, and if I put all of the letters in columns it will get too wide..

[image]

Here's my code:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\scriptsize
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{0.5}
\begin{tabular}{*{31}{c}}

A \u A \^A B C D E F G H I \^I J K L M N O P Q R S \c S T \c T U V W X Y Z\\
\hspace{0.5pt}\\
\hline
\hspace{0.5pt}\\
K O \c S \^I U J R W \u A N \^A F D B Y Q H V G I E P \c T A X Z T S L C M\\
\end{tabular}


$$\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c||}
\hline
A & \u A & \^ A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & \^ I & J & K & L & M & N & O & P & Q & R & S & \c S & T & \c T & U & V & W & X & Y & Z\\
\hline
K & O & \c S & \^ I & U & J & R & W & \u  A & N & \^ A & F & D & B & Y & Q & H & V & G & I & E & P & \c T & A & X & Z & T & S & L & C & M\\
\hline
\end{tabular}$$
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Sure, thanks for pointing it out. This is my first post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution which (a) employs a `tabular*` environment (with  its overall width set to `\textwidth`) and (b) employs the `\midrule` macro of the `booktabs` package to draw a well-spaced horizontal line. Hence, there's no need to fiddle with `\arraystretch`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \midrule macro
\begin{document}

\begingroup % limit scope of next instruction to current group
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX determine amount of intercolumn padding
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{31}{c}}
A & Ă & Â & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & Î & J & K & L &
M & N & O & P & Q & R & S & Ș & T & Ț & U & V & W & X & Y & Z \\ 
\midrule
K & O & Ș & Î & U & J & R & W & Ă & N & Â & F & D & B & Y &
Q & H & V & G & I & E & P & Ț & A & X & Z & T & S & L & C & M \\
\end{tabular*}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very elegant. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX.SX! I think, your approach using a `tabular` is already nice. You should probably not use vertical lines and omit the `\hline`s above and below the tabular. And there is no need to typeset the `tabular` in math mode. You can adjust the spacing by re-setting `\arraystretch` and `\tabcolsep`. In order to make these adjustments only for this `tabular`, you should place everything inside a group.

By the way, as long as you encode your file in UTF-8, you can type in the accented letters directly and, due to this fact, even use the proper characters for Romanian (S and T with comma below).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begingroup
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}   % change vertical spacing
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.6pt}       % change horizontal spacing
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc} 
A & Ă & Â & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & Î & J & K & L & 
M & N & O & P & Q & R & S & Ș & T & Ț & U & V & W & X & Y & Z \\ \hline 
K & O & Ș & Î & U & J & R & W & Ă & N & Â & F & D & B & Y & 
Q & H & V & G & I & E & P & Ț & A & X & Z & T & S & L & C & M \\ 
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful! Also, thanks a lot for the tip encoding in UTF-8.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

With `tabularray` package and `X` columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begingroup
\begin{tblr}{colsep=0pt, colspec={*{31}{X[c]}}}
A & Ă & Â & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & Î & J & K & L &
M & N & O & P & Q & R & S & Ș & T & Ț & U & V & W & X & Y & Z \\ 
    \hline
K & O & Ș & Î & U & J & R & W & Ă & N & Â & F & D & B & Y &
Q & H & V & G & I & E & P & Ț & A & X & Z & T & S & L & C & M \\
\end{tblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]